# Classic scripts vs. module scripts in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, module, es6-modules

I was going through the [WHATWG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHATWG) specifications for `async` and `defer` attributes for the `<script>` tag, when I saw this statement:

> [Classic scripts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#classic-script) may specify `defer` or `async`; [module scripts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#module-script) may specify `async`.

I went through the WHATWG definitions for **classic** and **module** scripts, but I didn't really get much clarity. In simple terms, what are the differences between **classic** and **module** scripts in JavaScript?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A *classic script* is just a standard JavaScript script as you know it. A *module script* is one that contains an [ES6 module](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html), i.e. it uses (or: can use) `import` and `export` declarations.

From [§8.1.3.8 Integration with the JavaScript module system](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#integration-with-the-javascript-module-system):

> The JavaScript specification defines a syntax for modules, as well as
>   some host-agnostic parts of their processing model. This specification
>   defines the rest of their processing model: how the module system is
>   bootstrapped, via the `script` element with `type` attribute set to
>   `"module"`, and how modules are fetched, resolved, and executed.
>   [[JAVASCRIPT]](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/)
>
> *Note:* Although the JavaScript specification speaks in terms of "scripts" versus "modules", in general this specification speaks in
>   terms of [classic scripts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#classic-script)
>   versus [module scripts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#module-script),
>   since both of them use the script element.

Also have a look at https://blog.whatwg.org/js-modules.

Comment: This is obviously correct, but it supplies so little information that I still feel unsatisfied.  The *classic scripts* link the OP provided is useless documentation (which is likely why there was confusion).  This answer "simply" gives the underlying mechanics.  But my question -- and presumably others' -- is how to use it?  For instance, in other languages, a module is anything you (can) import and a script is anything you (can) execute.  But the definition is typically a bit "fuzzy".  In new JS it seems they want more rigor.  But what is the best practice??

Comment: Actually, presuming [this documentation](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/) is still accurate, it was far more helpful.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson JS does use the term "module" in a very fuzzy meaning as well ("some piece of code that creates an object to make things available to the public"), but in the question and therefore this answer we specifically refer to ES6 module syntax.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson I just presumed everyone knew "ES6 modules" by now, that's why I didn't include a link. Edited.

Answer (score 51):

Here are the differences I have noted from various articles. If you want more details, read a complete article on the internet:

1. Modules are singleton. They will be loaded and executed only once.
2. Modules can use import and export.
3. Modules are always executed in strict mode.
4. All objects (class, const, function, let, or var) are private unless explicitly exported.
5. The value of `this` is undefined at the outer scope (not window).
6. Modules are loaded asynchronously.
7. Modules are loaded using CORS. see Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.
8. Modules don't send cookies and authentication info by default. See `crossorigin="use-credentials"`.
9. Imports are resolved statically at load time rather than dynamically at runtime.
10. HTML comments are not allowed.