# ES6 modules in the browser: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, module, es6-modules

I'm new to **ES6** (ECMAScript 6), and I'd like to use its **module system** in the browser. I read ES6 is supported by Firefox and Chrome, but I'm getting the following error using `export`

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

I have a test.html file

```
<html>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and a test.js file

```
'use strict';

class Test {

    static hello() {
        console.log("hello world");
    } 
}

export Test;
```

Why?

Comment: ES6 *modules* are not yet supported in the browser. Also you're still loading a script, not a module.

Comment: I still don't understand the difference between a script and a module

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39652842/1048572)

Comment: The important part I have come to notice is ```<script type="module"></script>``` make sure you add that otherwise you will get that error. I was banging my head on the wall continually doing ```<script>import ... </script>``` knowingly that chrome is now said to support ES6 modules without flags, then I noticed that the type attribute was needed to specify to the browser that this is an ES6 module, without which you get that exact error.

Comment: I am using Chrome 68, I still see this error when we use import * from

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Many modern browsers now support ES6 modules. As long as you import your scripts (including the entrypoint to your application) using `<script type="module" src="...">` it will work.

Take a look at [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module) for more details:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module

Answer (score 53):

You can try ES6 Modules in Google Chrome Beta (61) / Chrome Canary.

Reference Implementation of ToDo MVC by Paul Irish - https://paulirish.github.io/es-modules-todomvc/

I've basic demo -

```js
//app.js
import {sum} from './calc.js'

console.log(sum(2,3));
```

```js
//calc.js
let sum = (a,b) => { return a + b; }

export {sum};
```

```html
<html> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>ES6</h1>
        <script src="app.js" type="module"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's right... The important part I have come to notice is ```<script type="module"></script>``` make sure you add that otherwise you will get that error. I was banging my head on the wall continually doing ```<script>import ... </script>``` knowingly that chrome is now said to support ES6 modules without flags, then I noticed that the type attribute was needed to specify to the browser that this is an ES6 module.

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 24,
  "colno": 8
}

Comment: I got above error by run your code snippet above, use chrome v67, why?

Comment: @hoogw Stackoverflow added that Run code snippet automatically. This code cannot be executed as is.

You have to copy the code to index.html and separate .js files as showed above and try in the browser!

Comment: Thank useful answer. I removed snippet runner for you. (As I saw StackOverflow snippets can't to has more than one `js` source).

Comment: My chrome Version 90.0.4430.93 Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
While I am just trying to use in my JS file only. @RoopeshReddy can you please help me out here.

Answer (score 25):

Unfortunately, modules aren't supported by many browsers right now.

> This feature is only just beginning to be implemented in browsers natively at this time. It is implemented in many transpilers, such as TypeScript and Babel, and bundlers such as Rollup and Webpack.

Found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: I read this feature was implemented in a Sof question, but theMDN source is actually more reliable.

Comment: According to the following link Chrome 61 should support import - it doesn't.
https://medium.com/dev-channel/es6-modules-in-chrome-canary-m60-ba588dfb8ab7

Comment: You have to add type="module" to your script tag.

Answer (score 12):

it worked for me **adding `type="module"`** to the script `import`ing my mjs:

```
<script type="module">
import * as module from 'https://rawgit.com/abernier/7ce9df53ac9ec00419634ca3f9e3f772/raw/eec68248454e1343e111f464e666afd722a65fe2/mymod.mjs'

console.log(module.default()) // Prints: Hi from the default export!
</script>
```

See demo: https://codepen.io/abernier/pen/wExQaa

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you changed an existing script to a module and forgot to remove the original script tag.  This is what happened to me and how I got directed to this page.  I had originally had this:

```html
<script src="app.js" defer></script>
```

Then I changed my main script tag to import it as a module and it was working, but I still received the error.  I couldn't figure out how it could be working and throwing an error, but I had forgotten to remove the original script tag.