# Unexpected token import : vue js with laravel

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I have created laravel setup and trying to configure vue js. for that i wrote code in app.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue';

import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import axios from 'axios';
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

import App from './App.vue';
import CreateItem from './CreateItem.vue';
import DisplayItem from './DisplayItem.vue';
import EditItem from './EditItem.vue';
```

But it's giving me in **chrome** error like: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import**

and in **firefox** it is giving error like : **import declarations may only appear at top level of a module**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722621/es6-in-the-browser-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep your import at the top of your file, like this :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import axios from 'axios';


import App from './App.vue';
import CreateItem from './CreateItem.vue';
import DisplayItem from './DisplayItem.vue';
import EditItem from './EditItem.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);
```