# Call JavaScript function from another JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, function, console.log

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="./first.js"></script>
    <script src="./second.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

In the *first.js* file, I want to call the functions from *second.js*:

```
secondFun(); // calling a function from second.js file
```

This is second.js file:

```
function secondFun() {
    console.log('second function called!!')
}
```

Comment: Simply reverse the order of your included scripts. That will solve your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a javascript function in another js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962958/calling-a-javascript-function-in-another-js-file)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

tl;dr: Load your dependencies **before** you depend on them.

---

You can't call a function that hasn't been loaded.

The functions defined in your second JS file won't be loaded until the first file has finished running all the top-level statements.

Reverse the order of your script elements.

Answer (score 8):

Use `import/export` introduced in [ECMAScript 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) (ES6) specification.

*second.js*

```
export function secondFun() {
    console.log('second function called!!')
}
```

*first.js*

```
import { secondFun } from 'second.js';
```

Then call `secondFun()` in the first file.

Comment: it said "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722621/es6-in-the-browser-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import

Answer (score 5):

A function cannot be called unless it was defined in the same file or one loaded before the attempt to call it.

A function cannot be called unless it is in the same or greater scope then the one trying to call it.

You declare function fn1 in first.js, and then in second you can just have fn1();

1.js :

```
function fn1 (){
    console.log('second function called!!')
}
```

2.js :

```
fn1();
```

index.html :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="2.js"></script>
```

It works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

in  **second.js**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  function secondFun(){
    console.log('second function called!!')
    }
});
```

haven't test but suppose to work

Even your js not right queue function order this function will wait until all files loaded to execute

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a function which i not in available yet there. So, you can't use in such case. But what you can do:

1. Reverse the order.
2. Use `defer` attribute on the script file.

#### 1.

You have to load your functions before to use them. So, reverse the order of the scripts.

#### 2. [*Source*](https://davidwalsh.name/script-defer)

`defer` Attribute is one of the seldom used attributes. As you can probably tell by the name of the attribute, defer instructs the contents of the script tag to not execute until the page has loaded.

#### [*Demo@plnkr*](https://plnkr.co/edit/svxAYpcNv3tvOypq1zl3?p=preview)