# how to export and import default function

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have one file which defines a single "default" function, and I want to import it in other:

HelloLog.js:

```
exports.default = (str) => {
    console.log(`Hello, logging ${str}!`);
}
```

Client.js:

```
const HelloLog = require('./HelloLog');

HelloLog.default("foobar"); // do not want

// I'd rather just do this:
HelloLog("foobar")
```

The fact is I get an error if I do it like in the second call above.

Question is: how should I change HelloLog.js so that second option on file Client.js would work?

Comment: you have to use `module.exports = (str) => {` to use `HelloLog("foobar")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Javascript's IMPORT EXPORT working. Do I need transpiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56959001/how-to-get-javascripts-import-export-working-do-i-need-transpiler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using **CommonJS** [Nodejs Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)

exporting one module  :
HelloLog.js :

```
module.exports = (str) => {
    console.log(`Hello, logging ${str}!`);
}
```

Client.js :

```
const HelloLog = require('./HelloLog');

HelloLog("foobar")
```

---

using **ECMAScript**
[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) [Nodejs Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html)

HelloLog.js :

```
// Default exports choose any
export default expression;
export default function (…) { … } // also class, function*
export default function name1(…) { … } // also class, function*
export { name1 as default, … };
```

Client.js :

```
import HelloLog from './HelloLog';

HelloLog("foobar")
```

---

- CommonJS and ECMAScript can't be mixed.

Comment: So basically we have `exports.default`, `module.exports`, and maybe `module.exports.default`? No, wait, the third form is not valid... This is giving me a headache already...

Comment: when you did `module.exports.default` you actually added default prop to the exported object `{default : (str)=>{}}`  [check out the documentations](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports_shortcut)

Comment: `module.exports.anyThing` and  `module.exports.default` there is no saved word as i know. no default or any other word.
then in your code you will do `const { anyThing ,  default, } = require('./Hello')` while if you don't want to use the exports object you shall do as i wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Or this.

```
module.exports = (str) => {
  console.log(`Hello, logging ${str}!`);
}
```

```
const HelloLog = require('./HelloLog');

HelloLog("foobar");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

HelloLog.js:

```
exports.HelloLog = (str) => {
    console.log(`Hello, logging ${str}!`);
}
```

Client.js:

```
const { HelloLog } = require('./HelloLog');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are naming your export `default`.
Try this:

```
export default (str) => {...}
```