# vue plugin throws error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, npm, es6-modules

I wanted to check out vue and use it for my next project. I wanted to use Hooper, a image carousel. I've installed it via `npm install hooper`. Now in my script file I use

```
  import { Hooper, Slide } from 'hooper';
  import 'hooper/dist/hooper.css';

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
      Hooper,
      Slide
    }
  }
```

But that already throws an error in the first line:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

I've already installed it in one folder above the script file, besides it, and in a folder, but the `js file` does not recognize the bracket. How do I solve this?

Comment: Do you use webpack? Or just trying to run this code via browser? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722621/es6-in-the-browser-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import

Comment: _"Now in my script file..."_ which script file is that?

Comment: No, I don't use webpack, because I use Kirby as CMS, and there is no documentation in using a copiler with a CMS. Of course I want to use it in my browser, where else lol

Comment: Correct me if I get any of this wrong but I'm guessing this is in a `.js` file and you are running `node path/to/script.js` and seeing the error in your terminal / cli. If so, check out [How can I use an es6 import in node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node)

Comment: I've also tried to use this script inside my html file, between script tags, but still got this error.

Comment: Are you reading any of the links we're giving you?

Comment: Like this: <template>
  <hooper :settings="hooperSettings">
    <slide>
      slide 1
    </slide>
    <slide>
      slide 2
    </slide>
    ...
  </hooper>
</template>

<script>
import { Hooper, Slide } from 'hooper';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Hooper,
    Slide
  },
  data() {
    return {
      hooperSettings: {
        itemsToShow: 2,
        centerMode: true
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>

Comment: So is it right to assume that you are including vuejs as a script in your html header? Something like `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Ok; I did not know that I have to wrap the script inside `<script type="module"></script>` 
Apparently it works now. Thanks?