# How to run moduled typescript output using regular script tag?

Tags: javascript, typescript

i'm not very familiar with the JavaScript ecosystem, so not exactly sure if my title is correct ... I wrote a simple application with pure ES6 with the help of lots of "googling", but i kept on getting type errors, hence decided switching to TypeScript.

At first i was excited,

```
let blah: String = "hello world";
console.log(blah);
```

and running `tsc blah.ts` outputted

```
var blah = "hello world";
console.log(blah);
```

which seemed very simple, i just included

```
<script src="ts/blah.js"></script>
```

and that console.log would print.

I decided to make use of modules to see how i would build something much bigger, so i created a `lib.ts`

```
export class StringUtil {

    private rawValue: String;

    constructor(input: String) {
        this.rawValue = input;
    }

    upper(): String {
        return this.rawValue.toUpperCase();
    }

}
```

and updated my original example to

```
import { StringUtil } from "./lib";

let blah: String = "hello world";
// console.log(blah);
console.log(new StringUtil(blah).upper());
```

running `tsc *.ts` now outputs:

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var lib_1 = require("./lib");
var blah = "hello world";
// console.log(blah);
console.log(new lib_1.StringUtil(blah).upper());
```

Refreshing the browser, i now get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at blah.js:2
```

So after lots of reading, i've seen many suggest that i add a TypeScript Config file which i did,

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "watch": true
    }
}
```

which outputs exactly the same and still have the same error:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var lib_1 = require("./lib");
var blah = "hello world";
// console.log(blah);
console.log(new lib_1.StringUtil(blah).upper());
//# sourceMappingURL=blah.js.map
```

someone suggested using amd as the module type:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "amd",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "watch": true
    }
}
```

this now outputs:

```
define(["require", "exports", "./lib"], function (require, exports, lib_1) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var blah = "hello world";
    // console.log(blah);
    console.log(new lib_1.StringUtil(blah).upper());
});
//# sourceMappingURL=blah.
```

and the browser complains:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at blah.js:1
```

switching to "umd" for the module, the browser error goes away, but the `console.log` no longer triggers due to the output being inside an anonymous function that i have no idea how to call

```
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") {
        var v = factory(require, exports);
        if (v !== undefined) module.exports = v;
    }
    else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define(["require", "exports", "./lib"], factory);
    }
})(function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var lib_1 = require("./lib");
    var blah = "hello world";
    // console.log(blah);
    console.log(new lib_1.StringUtil(blah).upper());
});
//# sourceMappingURL=blah.js.map
```

I've tried removing the module param as some StackOverflow posts suggested, but it continues to output the same as the commonjs option.

Switching to target "es6" and module "amd", the console.logs are still inside a function,

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "amd",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "watch": true
    }
}
```

```
define(["require", "exports", "./lib"], function (require, exports, lib_1) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    let blah = "hello world";
    // console.log(blah);
    console.log(new lib_1.StringUtil(blah).upper());
});
//# sourceMappingURL=blah.js.map
```

but the browser complains

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at blah.js:1
```

The more i'm reading, the more conflicting suggestions i'm seeing, most posts never mention what version of TypeScript they are using, so i'm assuming there are different ways to do things depending on your version?

`tsc --version` says i'm on 3.6.3

What is the correct way to make `tsc blah.ts` output something that i can just include via a script tag in my index.html? I'm not using NodeJS, this is just a static HTML file. "umd" which is not showing errors in the console is also using `exports` so i guess if i manage to call that generated anonymous function somehow, it too would complain about the `exports`.

Since this is going to be a small application that is doing basic DOM manipulation, how do i get `tsc` to combine all the files into a single JS file so that i don't have js files being loaded at runtime? Or is it possible to include each of the generated js files individually via script tags doing something like this?

```
<script src="ts/lib.js"></script>
<script src="ts/blah.js"></script>
```

I would prefer not using anything extra, i saw many posts about webpack, babel, gulp, etc etc etc. That seems to make things more complicated.

Some other StackOverflow posts suggests using

```
tsc --out app.js blah.ts lib.ts --module
```

that then complains

```
Cannot compile modules using option 'out' unless the '--module' flag is 'amd' or 'system'.
```

So i add the "amd" module flag:

```
tsc --out app.js blah.ts lib.ts --module amd
```

which then outputs:

```
define("lib", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    exports.__esModule = true;
    var StringUtil = /** @class */ (function () {
        function StringUtil(input) {
            this.rawValue = input;
        }
        StringUtil.prototype.upper = function () {
            return this.rawValue.toUpperCase();
        };
        return StringUtil;
    }());
    exports.StringUtil = StringUtil;
});
define("blah", ["require", "exports", "lib"], function (require, exports, lib_1) {
    "use strict";
    exports.__esModule = true;
    var blah = "hello world";
    // console.log(blah);
    console.log(new lib_1.StringUtil(blah).upper());
});
```

add app.js via script tag

```
<script src="ts/app.js"></script>
```

once again the browser console complains:

```
app.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at app.js:1
```

switching from "amd" to "system", the browser complains

```
app.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
    at app.js:1
```

Besides the error in the browser console, my `console.log` code snippet is still sitting inside an anonymous function which i don't know how to call.

Any suggestions on how to get something this simple working with TypeScript?

Comment: Commonjs, AMD and System require loader libraries to be used in the browser. Use `None` or `ES6` for the `module` option, depending on what you want.

Comment: That makes total sense, so CommonJS and AMD requires some third-party stuff to work. Going the ES6 route, i'm getting `Cannot use import statement outside a module`. How do i create a TypeScript module that can still trigger the console.log as soon as the page loads?

Comment: If you want to go the ES6 route with modern browsers, you need to [include the modules accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41722621/1048572)

Comment: Check this for typescript using systemjs. I had all of the above issues - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61497363/405022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ES2015` as `module` and `target` in your `tsconfig.json` load it as:

```
<script src="ts/blah.js" type="module"></script>
```

**Edit:** 
You will probably get an `404 not found` error because as per today (January 18, 2020) javascript module feature needs that the import is done using the file extension. That is:

```
import {myLib} from 'path/to/my/file.js'
```

but javascript does not emit the `.js` [This is a know issue/feature request for Typescript regarding modules](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577).

As workaround you can write an npm script that parses the generated javascript files and fix the extension like the one used in [this Logger lib](https://github.com/distante/saninn-logger/blob/master/scripts/fix-es2015-modules.js)

Comment: Is there a difference between ES6 and ES2015? I've switched to ES2015 now and using that script tag with the `type="module"` and i'm getting a 404: `http://localhost:63342/www/www.main/ts/lib net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

I can access both JS files, `http://localhost:63342/www/www.main/ts/blah.js` and `http://localhost:63342/www/www.main/ts/lib.js` and my index.html is sitting at `http://localhost:63342/www/www.main/index.html`. Is it supposed to try and access `lib` instead of `lib.js`?

Comment: Changing `import { StringUtil } from "./lib";` to `import { StringUtil } from "./lib.js";` does work. Wow, that's super annoying!

Comment: ES6 and ES2015 seems to both work though, so i'm assuming they're exactly the same?

Comment: It seems if i add a .js extension to my typescript import, TypeScript still picks it up and then outputs it with .js: `import {StringUtil} from "./lib.js";`
So i guess this hack means no npm watcher hack is required

Comment: @JanVladimirMostert yes that also works AFAIK but I have not test it. I tend to use the npm script in watch mode because I usually just let vscode do the imports automatically. Also yes ES6 and ES2015 are the same thing.