# Typescript: leaving out 'export' keyword appears to make an interface global?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Recently I had the following situation in VSCode in a typescript project:

file: `some-interface.ts`

```js
// no import statements have been skipped. This is the whole file:
export interface SomeInterface {
    property: AnotherInterface;         
}
```

and file: `another-interface.ts`:

```js
export interface AnotherInterface {
    // ...
}
```

Okay - as there is no import statement in the `some-interface.ts` VS code showed me the error that the type `AnotherInterface` could not be found. Of course this is expected behavior. **But as soon I accidently removed the `export` keyword from `another-interface.ts` - VS code stopped complaining and could correctly resolve the type.**

So do anyone know what's going on here? Is this expected behavior or rather a bug of either typescript or vs code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So do anyone know what's going on here? Is this expected behavior or rather a bug of either typescript or vs code?

This is the expected behavior. If there is no `export` neither `import` in a file, then it is a *script* instead of a module. Then, in a script, all members are global.

See also: [Classic scripts v/s module scripts in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652618/classic-scripts-v-s-module-scripts-in-javascript)